# Transforming Ubuntu into elementary OS

Tags: release-loki

I use a series of Docker containers as VMs for unit/integration testing. I have some Ansible roles which I use for configuring my elementary OS systems. (Full disclosure: I'm a SRE nerd)

In order to run my tests against elementary OS, I'd like to bake a Docker image for elementary. The only way I can see to do this is to base the image on Ubuntu 16.04 and somehow transform the system into elementary OS.

How can I go about doing this? Is there a list of repositories I need to install? If I just install `elementary-desktop`, is that all that is needed? I'm assuming that some lsb-release hacks need to happen too.

---

EDIT: I'm attempting to do so [here on GitHub](https://github.com/naftulikay/docker-loki-vm). Fingers crossed!

Answer (score 0):

I may be misunderstanding, but it sounds like you want an Elementary base image.  You could always try rolling your own following these instructions:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/baseimages/

I would guess (though I don't know), that you might be able to use the mentioned debootstrap tool to create one given it also works with Ubuntu - ie, what Elementary extends.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this already exists?
https://hub.docker.com/r/elementary/docker/